# How to save data in Go struct from function/method?

Tags: class, go, data-structures, struct

I'm just starting out with Go and I'm having a hard time saving data in a `struct`. Coming from other languages I learned there is no such thing as a `class` in Go. For similar purposes, the `struct` can be used, and functions can be "added" to the struct. So I wrote the following simple program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
    the_number int
}
func (self MyStruct) add(another_number int) int {
    self.the_number += another_number  // I save the result to the struct the_number
    return self.the_number
}

func main() {
    my_struct := MyStruct{1}
    result := my_struct.add(2)
    fmt.Println(result)               // prints out 3 as expected
    fmt.Println(my_struct.the_number) // prints out 1. Why not also 3?
}
```

As you can see from the comments I'm puzzled by the fact that the result is not saved in `self.the_number` in the instantiated `my_struct`.

So I found out I can get around this by doing

```
my_struct.the_number = my_struct.add(2)
```

But I methods/functions can sometimes become complex in which I want to save a lot of data to the `my_struct` from within the function.

Could any smarter soul than me give me a tip on what I'm missing here?

How can I save data to an instantiated `struct` from within a function?

Comment: Don't use `self`; use a descriptive name instead.

Comment: You're missing pointers. Maybe start with the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/), which covers all the basics, including [pointers](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1)

Comment: Do you really have to downvote this one?

Comment: Duplicate, the 20ths.

Comment: @akond: downvote = "This question does not show any research effort." Asking this question for the Nth time doesn't show research effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use pointer in struct method `func (self *MyStruct) add(another_number int) int` as without the `*` variable (self) is passed by value, not by references. E.g. you are updating a copy of an original object and this changes are discarded.

It's a basic stuff and well covered in [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) - everyone should take it before starting coding in Go.

Another option would be return the `self` from the method - it would follow "immutable" style so you can write code like: `my_struct = my_struct.add(1).add(2)`

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
    the_number int
}
func (self *MyStruct) add(another_number int) int {
    self.the_number += another_number
    return self.the_number
}

func main() {
    my_struct := MyStruct{1}
    result := my_struct.add(2)
    fmt.Println(result)               // prints out 3 as expected
    fmt.Println(my_struct.the_number) // prints out 1. Why not also 3?
}
```

Comment: To whomever downvoted this question; why did you downvote? The solution seems to work perfect.